# Best way to preserve guanciale (or other cured meats) in the fridge

Tags: storage-method, food-preservation, storage

I have a 1.2 KG piece of [guanciale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guanciale) currently still vacuum sealed. It will take a few months to eat so, once opened, what should it be wrapped it in to maximize it's lifespan in the fridge?

Are the following suitable?

- Baking Paper
- Freezer Paper
- Parchment Paper
- Cling film aka Plastic wrap
- Cheesecloth - I have something called: grade 90 unbleached cotton cheesecloth
- Butcher's Paper - It's expensive in the UK because it only seems to be sold in large rolls (£18 for 50 metres on Amazon)

Answer (score 1):

If it is a cured product then it does not need refrigeration. A cured product has an indefinite lifespan, that was the whole point of curing to increase the lifespan of meat products.

Keep it away from bugs and rats and it should be OK. Maybe if you live in a humid tropic area you may have problems with mold growth but that is a stretch.

Answer (score 1):

Any of those wraps will be fine.  My typical practice, whether curing my own or purchasing a large amount, is to portion in to smaller pieces.  Those destined for storage get vacuum sealed.  If I have a lot, I freeze them.  The portions for daily use either get wrapped in butcher paper (if I have it) or, more often than not, placed in a zip-lock bag and refrigerated.

Answer (score -2):

It'll go bad as soon as you open the bag.

Cut in manageable chunks/portions,  wrap in cling film, and freeze each chunk individually.

If you have access to a vacuum machine, you could also vacuum each portion before freezing.

Comment: I think you mean “start to go bad”, rather than it’ll immediately go bad upon opening.

Comment: The point of curing meats is that they don't go bad as soon as raw meat. The exact expiry date will depend on the curing process used, and should be noted on the packaging OP has. Freezing is indeed an option, but storing in the fridge should also be one, unless the OP bought something that is only pseudo-cured.